# nil value of Blood Glucose from HealthKit

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I've inserted some glucose data in my device health kit app, and now trying to retrieve these inserted data but I'm getting this error:

```
2015-05-17 11:33:08.056 HKTutorial[687:125911] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to convert incompatible units: mg/dL, mol<180.1558800000541>'
```

This the method code I'm using to retrieve the glucose data:

```
func updateGlucose(){    
let sampleType = HKSampleType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBloodGlucose)


self.healthManager?.readMostRecentSample(sampleType, completion: { (mostRecentGluco, error) -> Void in

  if( error != nil )
  {
    println("Error reading blood sugar from HealthKit Store: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    return;
  }

  var glucoLocalizedString = self.kUnknownString;
  // 3. Format the weight to display it on the screen
  self.gluco = mostRecentGluco as? HKQuantitySample;

  if let mmol = self.gluco?.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.moleUnitWithMolarMass(HKUnitMolarMassBloodGlucose)) {
    let glucoFormatter = NSMassFormatter()
    glucoFormatter.forPersonMassUse = true;
    glucoLocalizedString = glucoFormatter.stringForObjectValue(mmol)!
  } else {
    println("error reading glucose data")
  }

  // 4. Update UI in the main thread
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    self.glucoLabel.text = glucoLocalizedString
    //self.updateBMI()

  });
});
}
```

The error breaks the code execution precisely at this line:

```
if let mmol = self.gluco?.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.moleUnitWithMolarMass(HKUnitMolarMassBloodGlucose)) {
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: I have not used HealthKit, but the error code looks clear. Attempt to convert incompatible units: mg/dL, mol<180.1558800000541>. Are you sure you can convert the first unit into the second? I would pull apart the call, and see what breaks.  For example does, let x = HKUnit.moleUnitWithMolarMass(HKUnitMolarMassBloodGlucose) work ?

Comment: thanks @DogCoffee for ur reply, the content of x constant is "mol<180.1558800000541>", it's obvious I'm passing just the unit while what I'm not managed to do is getting the actual data from the HealthKit!

Comment: So what if you do let y = doubleValueForUnit(x) | Does that result in the double value? Or does it crash?

Comment: If it works, then must be something with self.gluco?.quantity ? What type is  self.gluco?

Comment: it crashes, the doubleValueForUnit() is a function in HKQuantitySample class which used to retrieve a double value from a passed HKUnit parameter, the type of self.gluco is HKQuantitySample. @DogCoffee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that **glucose is measured as a concentration** but you are converting it to one volume x. **The two units used are `mmol/L` and `mg/dL`**. You are converting `mg/dL` to `mol<180.1558800000541>`, but instead you should be converting it to `mmol/L`.

Comment: Thanks @Schemetrical , I figured that out but I'm not sure yet of how to convert it from mg/dL to mmol/L in Swift,

Comment: To convert mmol/L to mg/dL just multiply by 0.055

Comment: @AliAlhamaly if this helped, please mark as correct, others who have the same problem (I've seen people do this by accident) will benefit from this.